# OpenGL ES 2 2D layered drawing

Tags: ios, opengl-es, drawing, opengl-es-2.0

I am rewriting an iPad drawing application with OpenGL ES2 instead of Core Graphics. 
I have already written a subclass of GLKView that can draw line segments and I can just drag a GLKView in my storyboard and set it a custom class. So far, drawing works, but I also want to implement layers like in Photoshop and GIMP.

I thought of creating multiple GLKViews for each layer and letting UIKit handle the blending and reordering, but that won't allow blend modes and may not have a good performance.

So far, I think doing everything in one GLKView is the best solution. I guess I will have to use some kind off buffer as a layer. My app should also be able to handle undo/redo, so maybe I will have to use textures to store  previous data.

However, I am new to openGL so my question is:
How should I implement layers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question is very broad, here is a broad and general answer that should give you some starting points for more detailed researches.

Probably a good way would be to manage the individual layers as individual *textures*. With the use of *framebuffer objects (FBOs)* you can easily render directly into a texture for drawing inside the layers. Each texture would (more or less) persistently store the image of a single layer. For combining the layers you would then render each of the layer textures one over the other (in the *appropriate order*, whatever that may be) using a simple *textured quad* and with the *blending* functions you need.

Comment: Great that you emphasised important keywords like *texture* and *framebuffer object*.

Comment: With such a broad question one cannot do much more than delegate the asker to the overall approach and provide some first google targets.